# Ruby How To Create a 2d Array Of Letters

Tags: ruby, arrays, 2d

I am trying to create a 2d array of NxN, and populate it with letters. I have a method to create the 2d array, but how can I iterate through each row and column an assign a random letter to it?

```
class Array2D
    def initialize(width, height)
        @data = Array.new(width) { Array.new(height) }
    end
    def [](x, y)
        @data[x][y]
    end
    def []=(x, y, value)
        @data[x][y] = value
    end
end
```

Comment: If it is `NxN`, then why does `initialize` take `width` and `height` separately?

Comment: If it is `NxN`, then why does `initialize` take `width` and `height` separately?

Comment: @sawa You can say that again!

Comment: If it is `NxN`, then why does `initialize` take `width` and `height` separately?

Answer (score 3):

If I may suggest... the [Matrix](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) library is pretty useful:

```
require 'matrix'
m = Matrix.build(5, 5) {|row, col| ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }

# => Matrix[["u", "f", "p", "o", "z"], ["h", "y", "e", "e", "l"], ["p", "q", "j", "i", "w"], ["r", "i", "d", "g", "w"], ["f", "a", "m", "u", "f"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use map!:

```
def initialize(width, height)
    @data = Array.new(width) { Array.new(height) }
    letters = ('a'..'z').to_a
    @data.map!{|row| row.map!{letters.sample}}
end

p Array2D.new(2,2) #=> <Array2D:0x1d43a50 @data=[["k", "x"], ["h", "f"]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

... or you can just flatten the 2D array into a simple array with N*N elements and use simple arithmetic on two indexes for retrieving and setting matrix elements, making initialisations and iterations extremely easy. Although this might bring problems with some other operations, it depends on how you intend to use this structure.